# Strange additional button added to Flask app with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am making a flask app and I'm still at the beginning when I've noticed a button is added to my page without it being in the html template.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>my page </title>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"rel="stylesheet"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style.css') }}">
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
        
      <header> 
          <h1>my page</h1>
      </header>
        <div class="firstrow">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button"><i class="material-icons">schedule</i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">contact</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">services</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">team</a>
          
        </div>
        <div class="secondrow">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" id=aparatura>aparatura</а>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" id=principles>principles</а>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" id=safety>safety</а>
        </div>
              
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you see there is nothing after the second row div, yet when [loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dekhA.png)
a strange extra button appears in the bottom left corner.
It is probably not a caching issue since when I change the html content and reload the changes are made to the page but the button remains. The CSS is applied to all `.btn` classes but there is no tag or anything after the second row div.

Is this a bootstrap problem?
What is this thing?

EDIT: I have discovered that replacing the last 3 "" tags with "" tags doesnt cause this behavior can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this to secondrow

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" id="aparatura">aparatura</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" id="principles">principles</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" id="safety">safety</a>
```

or rewrite the secondrow `</a>` end tags

Comment: oh wow i had the second closing a tag in cyrillic what a dumb dumb been stuck on it 2 hours. thank you